# event.js 85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event in mysql server

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have tried to start node js server with forever command, for few times its works fine but after some time it throws the error that server closed the connection.

I am using Hostgator linux os. I have also installed mysql for database operation.[image]

Can anybody please help me to find out the reason behind it lost the connection even we have started it with forever command ?

Answer (score 1):

Need to handle error like

```
connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```